# How would I destroy an object when it reaches a certain distance away from where it started?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I currently have a enemy(object) and a fireball(object). when the enemy detects a target it will shoot a fireball at said target. The problem I'm having is that if the fireball misses its target, it will continue moving forever and will prevent the enemy from shooting another fireball. It does not have this problem if the fireball hits the target.

I've tried getting the enemy's vector location and the fireball's vector location, then check the distance between the two is greater than the threshold that will trigger it to destroy the instance of the fireball. **However it keeps telling me its missing a reference to the enemy object.** I'm hoping this code will be enough to solve my problem.

Enemy Script:

```cs
    private Vector3 E_pos

    //this method finds the vector3 position of the enemy
    public Vector3 getEnemyPos()
    {
        e_Pos = transform.position;
        return e_Pos;
    }
```

FireBall Script:

```cs
    private  Vector3 f_Pos;
    private Vector3 e_Pos;
    WanderingAI w = new WanderingAI();

    void Update()
    {
        e_Pos = w.getEnemyPos();
        transform.Translate(0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if(totalDistance() > 10f || totalDistance() < -10f)
        {
            Debug.Log("Distance from Enemy: " + totalDistance());
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
    //this method finds the current vector3 Coordinates for the fireball instance 
    public Vector3 getCurrentFireballPos()
    {    
        f_Pos = transform.position;
        return f_Pos;
    }
    //This method finds the total distance between the fireball instance and the enemy
    public float totalDistance()
    {
        float data = 0;
        data = Vector3.Distance(getCurrentFireballPos(), w.getEnemyPos());
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: How can `totalDistance()` ever return something less than 0, let alone less than -10?

Comment: Why are you trying to instantiate a `WanderingAI` in the fireball code? Which "enemy (object)" are you talking about? You have to tell the fireball which one you're talking about, and doing `new WanderingAI()` attempts to create a completely new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your main issue seems not to be the calculation but a missing reference. Your code is by far not enough to tell why it is not working but I'll try:

In case the `WanderingAI` is a `MonoBehaviour` component (which seems to be the case since you are trying access `transform`

```
WanderingAI w = new WanderingAI();
```

is an absolute **no go**! This component should be attached to a `GameObject` and either set when instantiating or has to be found on runtime dynamically.

I would guess the missing reference exception isn't thrown for `w` but rather for the line

```
transform.position
```

in `getEnemyPos`.

We don't see where or how you Instantiate this. So just as an example you **could** (see better way below) simply hand the instantiated fireball the `Transform` reference of who fired it:

In the fireball have a field

```
public Transform enemyTransform;
```

and then set it together with the instantiation

```
public Fireball fireballPrefab;

...

var fireball = Instantiate(fireballPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
fireball.enemyTransform = transform;
```

Your get position methods are quite redundant. `transform.position` is always public for any `GameObject` and `Componnet`(`MonoBehaviour`) reference so as soon as you have a reference to the enemy or your fireball (object or component doesn't matter) you can simply directly access e.g.

```
enemy.transform.position
```

And just general notes: Method names in c# should start with a capital letter. And storing every single value in a local variable or class field is also quite unnecessary.

---

### However

Instead of using the responsible enemy transform **at all** you could simply store the fireballs **own start position**. Then you wouldn't have to care about the enemy anymore. Also taking the enemy's position into account in `Update` might not work correctly if the enemy moves meanwhile ;)

Since you are only moving in the `z` direction you could simply check the so far traveled distance and wouldn't even need a reference to the enemy

```
// Adjust in the Inspector
[SerializeField] private float range = 10;

// Stores the initial position
private Vector3 startPosition;

private void Start()
{
    // Store position before starting to move
    startPosition = transform.position;
}

private void Update ()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    // Directly compare to the initial position
    // Without having to care who fired this ball
    if(Mathf.Abs(startPosition.z - transform.position.z) >= range)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    // Or simply
    if(Vector3.Distance(startPosition, transform.position) >= range)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

---

Currently you are also only moving in **global** Z direction .. is this really what you wanted to do? Otherwise I would rather set the correct rotation when instantiating the ball and move in its local forward direction like

```
transform.Translate(transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: I changed it to set the start position of the fireball when it instantiates and it works exactly how i wanted it too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most important part of this problem is that you should use prefabs for the fireballs, and create a new instance of the fireball prefab when needed.
Then I would choose from these 2 (or both at the same time):

1. **Create "imaginary" boundaries**: This one is the simplest of them all. For example, if your fireballs position on the y-axis reaches 50, it will be destroyed. You can create these rules for all dimensions.
2. **Distance from starting position**: You basically want to store the starting position of the object. Then in the update method just calculate the current distance from it somehow like:

   ```
   var f_pos = transform.position;
   double distance = Mathf.Abs(f_pos.x - startingPos.x) + Mathf.Abs(f_pos.z - startingPos.z) + Mathf.Abs(f_pos.y - startingPos.y);
   ```

Sorry if the code is not working with these parameters, I didn't test it, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: You would rather use `float distance = Vector3.Distance(f_pos, startingPos);`

Comment: @derHugo True, but my point was only that this problem doesn't need to be overcomplicated.

Comment: Well, that's what I mean ... `float distance = Vector3.Distance(f_pos, startingPos);` to me looks less complicated then doing `Mathf.Abs(f_pos.x - startingPos.x) + Mathf.Abs(f_pos.z - startingPos.z) + Mathf.Abs(f_pos.y - startingPos.y);` ;)